# Server-side Gitlab URL rewriting?

Tags: gitlab, dns, url

Our old BitBucket server had a URL like this,

- https://bitbucket.acme.net/scm/acmegroup/acme-project.git

And, we're wanting to move to GitLab with a DNS switch which has a different URL-convention namely

- https://gitlab.acme.net/acmegroup/acme-project.git

The `/scm/` is what I'd like to fix. Is there a way to rewrite URLs through configuration of the GitLab server such that I can make

- https://gitlab.acme.net/scm/acmegroup/acme-project.git

Redirect to

- https://gitlab.acme.net/acmegroup/acme-project.git

Note, I know I can change the "Custom Git clone URL for HTTP(S)" and *"Replaces the clone URL root"* under GitLab's `admin/application_settings/general`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitLab omnibus and self-managed installs ship with NGINX which is exposed and documented here,

- https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#inserting-custom-nginx-settings-into-the-gitlab-server-block

You basically edit the `gitlab.rb` file, edit `nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config']` and then rerun `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` to regenerate the nginx confs and restart nginx.